# Is there a way to synchronously invoke a event on AWS IoT Greengrass CoreDevice via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

Im trying to figure out a way to enable a synchronous communication flow from Lambda to a Greengrass core device.

An example would be of a scenario where a device would execute some code on the core device and would need to return a success or failure, eg to check if one particular SD Card is full or writable on the device. This check needs to be exposed via an api that would take a parameter(index of SD Card Slot) so that it can be invoked at will.

Is it possible to invoke a lambda function synchronously and wait for the response form IoT Core in a synchronous manner ?

All the documentation points to an asynchronous method of invocation via MQTT to the core device and create Rules on AWSIoTCore to trigger a lambda/notify SQS. This is ok if its only 1 Http Request at time, but in case of multiple request how can we identify the right message from the SQS Queue.

I would like to know how to wait for the result from IoTCore in the lambda before sending a response to the API.